# Redis flushall command is randomly being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I have a ruby app in production that uses sidekiq (that uses redis) and I have managed to discover that flushall commands are being called which cause the database to be wiped (thus removing all the processed and scheduled jobs).

I don't know or understand what could be causing this.
Does anyone know how I can begin to trace the call to flushall?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you read the Redis security page? http://redis.io/topics/security#network-security

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most likely that your Redis server is open to the public network without any protection - that is just calling for trouble because anyone can connect and do much more damage than just a FLUSHALL. If that it the case, use password authentication at the very least, after burning the compromised server - the attacker may have gained access to your server's operating system and from there who knows where. More information at: http://antirez.com/news/96

If that isn't the case and you have a rogue application somewhere that randomly calls unwanted commands, you can try tracking it by combining the [`MONITOR`](http://redis.io/commands/monitor) and [`CLIENT LIST`](http://redis.io/commands/client-list).

Lastly, you can consider renaming/disabling the FLUSHALL command, at least temporarily, until you get to the bottom of this.